# Internet explorer takes long to load form that calls long XML file via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer

I am trying to create an auto-complete drop-down field in a form. This works perfectly on Chrome, but when I try it in Internet Explorer it takes long to load and crashes. I tried this code with a smaller XML file and it worked. Do you have any recommendations of how to make it load easier? or have you seen this happen before with big XML files in Internet Explorer? This file has around 70,000 rows with each row 4 child rows.

```
$jQ(function() {
  $jQ.ajax({
    url: "url",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function( xmlResponse ) {
      var data = $jQ( "row", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
        var state = $jQ( "STATE", this ).text() ? ($jQ.trim( $jQ( "STATE", this ).text() ) + " - ") : "";
          var ceeb = $jQ( "ATP_CD", this ).text() ? ($jQ.trim( $jQ( "ATP_CD", this ).text() )) : "";

        return {
          value: $jQ( "DESCR", this ).text() + " - " + state + $jQ( "COUNTRY", this ).text(),
          ceeb: ceeb
        };
      }).get();

      $jQ( "#School_Name_Form_Lookup" ).autocomplete({
        source: data,
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(e, ui) {
          $jQ("#School_Name_Form_Lookup").attr("DESCR","").val(ui.item.value);
          $jQ("#CEEB_Code_RFI__c").val(ui.item.ceeb);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Big loops = Bad performance in IE

Comment: filter the data at server better...sending 300,000 results to browser doesn't make sense

Comment: the client will likely never need all 70k rows, using an ajax request to get results on each search rather than pulling them all up front should be more performant in this case.

Comment: @KevinB do you have any links or info that would help me doing that? thank you for your response